# Determine if android app has crashed or exited by user

Tags: android, crash

I want to know whether my app has crashed or exited by the user. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Save a value inside shared pref and remove it if application has been exited by user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this: [https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29), it may help :)

There's no such thing as exiting the application by the user. You can always do something when onStop() or [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) of your main activity is called, but that's all. Just note that it doesn't mean that the app was "exited", but only "left" by the user. You can of course  finish the activity from there to make sure the app is really exited.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there's no exit ideology in Android. Applications are kept on running in background and (if necessary) Android's VM automatically kill stale applications when it requires to free memory.

Regarding app-crash, if the app is crashed, so you may get notified on your Google Play's developer console in case the user has chosen to report the crash.

Comment: Or you could use some third party crash reporting libraries like BugSense or ACRA. It has been quite popular lately to add libraries. And in case of which crash reports are sent automatically without user's permission.

Comment: I want to know if the app has crashed, so that I can do something programatically with the app. So if it's been exited by the user - do this. If its crashed - do something else.

Comment: then you are not actually looking for crash. because once the app is crashed you cant even do that **something else** thing. All you need to do is to manage your code properly with try/catch blocks so that unexpected exceptions are caught before they kill the app